# OpenCV4Android SVM is not giving the correct prediction

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I am new to machine learning and openCV. I have taken a set of 10 images for each emotion(neutral and happy) from Cohn-Kanade face database. Then I have extracted the facial features from each image and put them in my trainingData Matrix and assigned the label for the respective emotion (Example: 0 for neutral and 1 for happy).

I have used the RBF kernel with gamma = 0.1 and C = 1. Once trained, I am passing the facial features extracted from the live camera frames from a smartphone camera for prediction. The prediction always returns 1.

If I increase the number of training samples for neutral expression(example: 15 neutral expression images and 10 happy expression images), then the prediction always returns 0 and if there are equal number of images for each expression in the training samples, then SVM prediction always returns 1.

Why is the SVM behaving this way? How to check if I am using the right values for gamma and C? Also, does SVM depend on the resolution of training images and testing images?

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to upload the SVM function so we can understand your code. Secondly, I have used SVM before and you need to normalize the training data and the labels. You should also make sure you are using the correct classifier as not all classifiers are supported. Follows this link for some tutorials http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html

For answering your other questions, unfortunately you have to find the best combination for gamma and C yourself, which is kind of the drawback of SVM. https://www.quora.com/What-are-C-and-gamma-with-regards-to-a-support-vector-machine

Yes, the SVM does depend on the resolution as your features/feature vectors would change depending on the resolution and hence the inputs and the labels.
P.S. This should ideally be in comments but unfortunately i don't have enough points to do that.